# VBA Label.Caption not updating on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform, caption

I've wasted a day trying all the possible solutions ive found on the internet so far and i give up xD
Im hoping someone far more proficient in Excel would be able to help me.

Basically, what im looking to do is after a user selects an option in a list box on a userform, i want labels to automatically update to show additional information about the option selected.

Im happy that the listbox selections work but i cant update the userform labels for the life of me.

Ive found a smaller section of code that should illustrate the problem more clearly

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim QuotNum As Integer

GenQuote.Caption = "New Quote Generation (Line 01)"

QuotNum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quote Generation").Cells(2, 1).Value

Me.Controls("Label1").Caption = "Quote Number - #" & QuotNum + 1
Me.Controls("Label3").Caption = "Quote Line Number - 01"

DoEvents
DoEvents

Me.Repaint
```

So the Userform is called "GenQuote"
and this code is located within the userform

Things i have tried already:

- Tried to update the captions from outside the userform, from a general module
- Found a website saying the problem was solved by adding 1/2 "DoEvents" so i tried that
- Ive tried Userform.Repaint of various forms
- Tried using a "CLng" function - but not entirely sure i was using it correctly as id never used it before
- Tried using Controls("Label").Caption, instead of Label.Caption
  Basically ive tried to apply any of the successful methods on the first page of google after inputting the title of this thread.

The odd thing is that when I hover over Me.Label.Caption = "New Text" after line execution, it has accepted the change but just not reflecting it in the userform.

Im baffled, so I'd be super grateful for any help :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried just about everything you mention and all of it works for me. Try it in fresh workbook.

Comment: And also, if that doesn't help - you can format text boxes to look and behave like text labels.

Comment: Why is code in the userform activate event rather than listbox change .?

Comment: Perhaps a "me.repaint" command before DoEvents?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the responses, in order...

Comment: Hey, thank you for the responses, in order...

- @Sam - The methods seem to work for many other people too from looking at successful solutions to similar problems to me. For any of the successful codes you've tried, could you show me some of the code that has worked on your system? If not ill try the textbox approach.

Comment: - @CDP1802 - Yes, the code was originally in Listbox_Change(), I've tried multiple different Sub descriptions this one was just the last one I tried I think.

Comment: - @pdtcaskey - I'll give that a go just in case I missed it!

Comment: I have tried the same example in a fresh workbook and it works...

So now, could anybody suggest why it wouldn't be working in my current workbook? :/

Comment: Two scenarios:
1. A collision of some kind. Remove half of everything in a copy. Repeat until it works
2. Some kind of corruption. Create a new workbook and copy half of everything until it works

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the problem, was a stupid error.

Im not dynamically controlling the dimensions of the label boxes. When I made the UserForm the labels for Label1 and Label3 were just big enough to contain the words that were originally there before updating.

I've increased the size of the labels now and works a charm!

The updated text was there, it was just hidden behind the boundaries of the label box.

Thanks to all who answered!